# Can an OLEDB connection string getting data from Access located in Dropbox to my Excel file cause sync problems for the users using the Access file?

Tags: excel, database-connection, connection-string, vba

So I have created a system at our office where I would use cloud computing systems (mainly Dropbox and Google Drive) to pull data daily. The system is as follows:

**Step 1 (If the file is not in the clouds yet):**
The relevant files (usually Excel and Access files) located at each User's desktop are automatically transferred to either Dropbox or Google Drive everyday at 4:30 pm by using a simple script and the Task Scheduler to automate the script activation. The folders where the files are saved on in Dropbox or Google Drive is shared to my account/employee account which will auto-sync on their computers. The script used is shown below:

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Test.MDB" "C:\Users\Asus\Google Drive" /Y /H /E /F /I
exit
```

**Step 2:** In my the Excel and/or Access files where I need the relevant files on, I will create a connection to link the files together. The image is shown below:

[image: Establishing a connection]

The connection string i'm using is an OLEDB connection string because my Access file is password protected. The string is shown below:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;C:\Users\Asus\Sample;Jet OLEDB:Database Password="abc123";
```

**Step 3:** I will then automatically refresh the data retrieved from the data connection by using Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) that is activated whenever the Workbook is opened. The script is simply:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Query - Sample Query").Refresh
```

**Concern/Issue:**

From this, my Excel spreadsheets will have very updated data without needing human intervention. However, my concern is if there will be synchronization issues with the files i'm connected to whenever I refresh the connection in Step 3. If the users are using the data files, is there a chance that a bug might occur and cause data loss such as corrupted files, conflicted copies, or any other bugs/problems?

One of the users claimed that the data they input this morning vanished. But I do not know if it's because of the fact that his assistant also used the file simultaneously, and perhaps he deleted the conflicted copy or if there was a problem with Dropbox not saving his file. It cannot be due to Step 1 because I did not use Step 1 on this case since it was already saved on the cloud to begin with. So i'm wondering if my data connection could have anything to do with it.

Comment: Have you actually tried updating the connection string manually?

Comment: What do you mean updating the connection string manually?

Comment: Oh I get what you mean. Yup I did the connection string works no problem. I am just concerned whether it can cause any bugs or problems when I refresh it when someone else is using